# How to declare a cursor to loop over some business unit in SQL server 2008 R2

Tags: stored-procedures, cursor, sql-server-2008-r2

I have some business unit such as India, International, US, UK. I have to:

1. Create a table variable (virtual in-memory table) with columns that match `SPROC SP_Report` resultset.
2. Declare a cursor that contains all business units and then the cursor should loop over the `BU's`.
3. For each `BU`, execute a stored procedure called `SP_Report` and insert the data into the table variable.
4. Finally I have to select the columns from the table `variable + timestamp + BU`, insert them into another table and clear the table variable.

What I have done so far, I have already made a stored procedure and table variabe:

**Code:**

```
declare @K table (BU nvarchar(max), K nvarchar(max),Y money, A money, D money, YP money) 
declare @FY int 
declare @BU nvarchar(max)

INSERT INTO @K (BU,K,Y,A,D,YP) EXEC dbo.SP_Report '2012', 'India'
SELECT * FROM @K
```

This code gives me the result of the table variable. Now I have to use it in cursor, which I don't know how to. How I can solve the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should be liske this (sory, I didn't tested it):

```
declare @KT table (BU nvarchar(max), K nvarchar(max),Y money, A money, D money, YP money) ;
declare @FY int ;
declare @BU nvarchar(max);
declare @K nvarchar(max);
declare @Y money;
declare @A money;
declare @D money;
declare @YP money;

INSERT INTO @KT (BU,K,Y,A,D,YP) EXEC dbo.SP_Report '2012', 'India'

DECLARE BU_cursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT BU,K,Y,A,D,YP FROM @KT;

OPEN BU_cursor;

FETCH NEXT FROM BU_Cursor 
INTO @BU,@K,@Y,@A,@D,@YP;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
  -- place the cursor logic here

  FETCH NEXT FROM BU_Cursor 
  INTO @BU,@K,@Y,@A,@D,@YP ;
END

CLOSE BU_Cursor;
DEALLOCATE BU_Cursor;
```